# Ajax call to ASP post method keep giving null parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a form to dynamically add item, you only need a name… I use KnockOut js for it
The html looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: tmgs">
    <i>Naam:</i>
    <input type="text" required data-bind="value: name" /><br />
</div><br/>
<button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: addtmg">New item</button>

<ul data-bind="foreach: tmgs">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="Save">Save Item</button>
```

The JS script I use looks like this:

```
 var model = {
        tmgs: ko.observableArray(),
        addtmg: function () {
            this.tmgs.push({ name: ko.observable() });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(model);
    var json = ko.toJSON(model);

    $("#Save").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AddItem")",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(model.tmgs)),
            success: function (status) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
    });
```

The ASP method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddItem(List<string> tmgs)
{
    if (tmgs == null)
    {
        return Json("False");
    }
    foreach (string item in tmgs)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            server.CreateItem(item);
        }
    }
    return Json("True"); 
}
```

When I run this code the method will receive a list but the lst contains only NULL items. I also used this:

```
$("#Save").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddItem")",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(model).tmgs,
        success: function (status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

And:

```
data: ko.toJSON(model.tmgs),
```

This time the parameter is not a list either and is just NULL

What am I doing wrong?

**Solution of @nemesv works**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddItem(List<Tmg> tmgs)
{
   ...
}

public class Tmg 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

In this case sending the data with `data: ko.toJSON(model.tmgs),` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your controller parameter which is a `List<string>` and the data what you are sending which is a **list of objects** with a `name` property containing the data.

So you need to send an array of strings with getting the `name` property of each tmg:

```
data: JSON.stringify(model.tmgs().map(function(item) { return item.name() })),
```

Or you need to change your controller to take a list of tmg objects:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddItem(List<Tmg> tmgs)
{
   ...
}

public class Tmg 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

In this case sending the data with `data: ko.toJSON(model.tmgs),` should work fine.

Comment: The second solutions seems to work, the first one still gives me a list with null values... but thanks it works for now :)

Comment: @Ferryzijl yeah, you are right I haven't noticed that `name` is also an observable and I've missed the `()` in the `map`. So this should work: `data: JSON.stringify(model.tmgs().map(function(item) { return item.name() })),`